# Enable Firebase debugView Events in React native

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, firebase-analytics

I have been trying to connect my ReactNative App to firebase for two reasons -
1. Push Notifications ( Done Successfully )
2. Events logging for each user.

I am facing issues with debugView to get live events in development mode, I am able to see my events in `streamView` but after some delay.

[image]

for the above -
for android - adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app "package_name"

and for ios, I have added `-FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled` to my xcode scheme.

but still none of these seems working.

I have RN0.44.

thank you,

Comment: I have the same problem.

Comment: @EarlFerguson: You need to add two things,`-FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled` , `-FIRDebugEnabled` and also make sure you have correct `Google-Services.json` , It will work.

Answer (score 13):

For ios, it's possible to launch app in the simulator with `FIRDebugEnabled` argument.

```sh
xcrun simctl launch "iPhone 8" com.your.package -FIRDebugEnabled
```

#### Edit:

I had to pass `FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled` to make debug view show data.

```sh
xcrun simctl launch "iPhone 8" com.your.package -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled
```

Comment: The answer was 3 years after the question, but was exactly what I needed when searching, so thanks!

Comment: perfect, thanks! btw `com.your.package` is the bundle identifier

Answer (score 3):

For others facing this issue, you can just run this command:

```
adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app <package_name>
```

[more details here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview)

Comment: this is only for Android, but the OP was asking about both Android and iOS

Answer (score 1):

In case you look for some alternative with `npx react-native`, you can try:

```
npx react-native run-ios --simulator="<simulator_name>" --scheme="<scheme_name>" -- -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll leave the Android details in this post.

1. Open the emulator with `yarn react-native run-android` or `npx react-native run-android`. This command also opens the JS server. Once it succeeds to open the app, proceed to the next step.
2. Use the command to check the device: `adb devices`. The app will disconnect, but it's fine. This step is to make sure adb uses the right emulator.
3. Enable the debug mode using adb: `adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app <package_name>`.
4. Use the opened emulator, search for the app with the <package_name>, and open it. If it is opened, close and re-open it.

You shall see the device shows up in the Firebase debug view.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (react native, iOS app) Debug View started working when I set the `analytics_auto_collection_enabled` flag to true. It was set to false as suggested in the Firebase docs.

firebase.json

```
{
  "react-native": {
    "analytics_auto_collection_enabled": true
  }
}
```